# Twitter APIによるcallbackの設定がうまくいかない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twitter

#### 前提・実現したいこと

現在、[この記事](https://qiita.com/cigalecigales/items/f4274088f20832252374)を参考に個人開発のWebアプリで、twitterアカウントを使ったサインアップ機構とログイン機構を作成しています。ですがtwitter Developersのcallbackの設定が分からず詰まっています。記事によって情報がバラバラで何のリンクで設定したら良いのか全く分かりません。とりあえず[この方の記事](https://saruwakakun.com/memo/omniauth-twitter)をもとに

http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/auth/twitter/callback
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/twitter/callback

を追加したのですが以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
callback URLは現在何にすればいいのでしょうか
回答よろしくお願いします。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
OAuth::Unauthorized
403 Forbidden
Extracted source (around line #236):
234
235
236
237
238
239

self.token_request(http_method, uri.path, token, request_options, arguments)
when (400..499)
raise OAuth::Unauthorized, response
else
response.error!
end

Rails.root: /home/ec2-user/environment/Qillion

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
oauth (0.5.4) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:236:in token_request'
oauth (0.5.4) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:155:in get_request_token'
omniauth-oauth (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:28:in request_phase'
omniauth-twitter (1.4.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:61:in request_phase'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in request_call'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:188:in call!'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/head.rb:14:in call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:277:in context'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:271:in call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in call'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in call_app'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in tagged'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:24:in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in call'
puma (3.12.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in call'
puma (3.12.2) lib/puma/server.rb:674:in handle_request'
puma (3.12.2) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in process_client'
puma (3.12.2) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in block in run'
puma (3.12.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in block in spawn_thread'
Request
Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response
Headers:

None
```

#### 補足情報

callback URL以外にも何かエラーの原因があれば教えてくださるお嬉しいです。

Comment: 回答される方へ https://teratail.com/questions/236134

Comment: 「users/auth/twitter/callback」ページは、あなたのWebサイトにありますか？コールバックURLについて、TwitterのAPIドキュメントに記載がありました。コールバック先は自分のWebサイトになるので、ページがないとエラーになるみたいです。https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/apps/guides/callback-urls